# Can you use .nextInt() for Java.util.Random and Java.util.Scanner in the same class?

Tags: java

I just started java so this will probably be pretty simple, but there are 4 of us in my class that cannot figure out what is wrong with this code. Im worried that it may be an overlap issue between the scanner and the random commands as .nextInt() is the command used for acquiring a new input and creating a random variable between 0 and n. Also, Im fairly new to Stackoverflow so if there are any procedures im breaking that i should try to accommodate in the future, id be happy to take your suggestions.

Thank you for you help in advance... cheers

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Question4 {
public static void main(String arg[]){
    //-----------------------------

    int numdice;
    int sides;
    int count = 1;
    int score;
    int total = 0;
    boolean loop = false;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();


    System.out.print("Enter how many dice you would like to roll:");
    numdice = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter how many sides to the dice there will be:");
    sides =  scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("You have rolled " + numdice + " dice with " + sides + " sides and have received the following values for each roll:");

    while (!loop) {
        if (numdice <= count){
            score = random.nextInt(sides -1 ) +1;
            total += score;
            System.out.print(score);
            ++count;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print(" your total value for your dices rolls are " + total);
            loop = true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();


    //-----------------------------
}

}
```

edits: the symptoms are that the program runs but does not create/prints any value for the random variable. The program will print the else statement but it claims that the total value = 0. There are no errors in the program or errors according to Eclipse. Also thank you for the note about spaces.

You guys are right that took care of it. how silly. dope. Thank you seth and paku! i would up rate you but it wont let me. Have a wonderful day regardless!

Comment: yes you can put rather than using import, give full import package with accessing item at the line of code where you are using it that for particular context.

Comment: What are the symptoms? What visible problem occurs when you try to run this? If you get an error message, copy/paste it into your question.

Comment: of course you can, Y not? please provide error stack!

Comment: You're not printing a space or newline between the scores, so they'll all be smushed together. If you roll 12, 2, and 14, you'll see 12214.

Comment: When you call something like `scan.nextInt()`, you are effectively calling `[MY-SCANNER-OBJECT].nextInt()` because when you created `scan` you created it as a `Scanner`. When the computer wants to invoke a method on an object, it goes to the object and calls the method that it defined. It's like telling a dog to speak. In dog terms, that means bark. For the computer to go to the `Human` method for no reason at all (having both in the same class isn't a reason) is absurd. If you call a method on an object that didn't directly or indirectly, (Inheritance), define a method, you will get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is backwards. `if (count <= numdice)`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Question4 {
public static void main(String arg[]){
    //-----------------------------

    int numdice;
    int sides;
    int count = 1;
    int score;
    int total = 0;
    boolean loop = false;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();


    System.out.print("Enter how many dice you would like to roll:");
    numdice = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter how many sides to the dice there will be:");
    sides =  scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("You have rolled " + numdice + " dice with " + sides + " sides and have received the following values for each roll:");

    while (!loop) {
        if (count <= numdice){
            score = random.nextInt(sides -1 ) +1;
            total += score;
            System.out.print(score + " ");  //Also, easier to read with a space.
            ++count;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Your total value for your dices rolls are " + total);
            loop = true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();


    //-----------------------------
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a problem with using `nextInt()` from both the Scanner and Random objects. The methods belongs to two completely different classes.

I think the if-statement inside your while loop is a bit backwards. You want to roll a dice numdice amount of times, correct? Because right now you're testing if numdice is less than your roll count. Is this what you wanted?

```
if (count <= numdice){
```

Answer (score 0):

Change if(numdice <= count) to if(numdice >= count), you will get the answer...